# AppCenter Failed to Fetch Updates

Tags: updates, appcenter

```
E: http://apt.last.fm/debian stable InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not resolve 'apt.last.fm')
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (non-free/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gotwig/weekly/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

This is the message I get after opening the AppCenter app within a popup.
Unfortunaly I don't get the errors there.
Could someone advise me ? I yet reinstalled the AppCenter but it is all the same.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output you have posted, two lines begin with an 'E' this denotes an error, while the 'W's are warnings. While warnings can be ignored (I'm not saying they should be, only that they can) an error can not, and will break the upgrade process.

The best course of action that comes to mind, is to remove the broken ppa's.

There's a link [here](https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-remove-delete-ppas-on-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint-elementary-os/#), containing several ways to handle that.

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer :)